# Parsing Flickr Image-URL with NSXMLParser

Tags: iphone, ios, nsxmlparser

I've the following problem:

I'm parsing an XML File from Flickr API http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags= with a specific tag, provided by the user before.

Then I get a XML file where in each 
`<entry>` item a line exists like

```
<link rel="enclosure" type="image/jpeg" href="IMAGEURL">
```

Is there an easy way to parse this line of code with NSXMLParser? Or should I use another way to get the `IMAGEURL`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the delegate method `parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:` to get that info. The attributes are available in the `attributesDict`. So you can get the `IMAGEURL` using,

```
NSString * imageURLString = [attributesDict objectForKey:@"href"];
```

when `elementName` is `"link"`.

Comment: Thanks, worked pretty well.

One further question:

Is it also possible to set 'objectForKey:@"rel"' to match this XML Key? It doesn't worked for me, but maybe I did something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this as well and it doesn't work anymore because the html is not well formed xml. This is the error I got: `NSXMLParserErrorDomain Code=111`

Now using the Flickr API and it works like a charm.
You have to create an API key: https://www.flickr.com/services/apps/create/